# Healthcare in UK for non-resident citizens

Tags: health, uk-citizens, dual-nationality

I have dual citizenship (U.K. and Canadian).  I am currently living in Canada, and will be going to U.K. for six weeks next July. I receive my state pension from U.K. Do I qualify for health care if needed?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of that question, with the additional explanation of that despite the fact that you are a pensioner receiving a U.K. State Pension, that does not in and of itself entitle you to NHs treatment. That's the only difference between the two questions, and the only point at which the answers could differ.